# How to use the results of ResultSet in an ADF iterator?

Tags: jsf, resultset, oracle-adf

I have a ResultSet being returned by a SQL statement. I wish to display the results using an ADF iterator. However, the `<af:iterator>` accepts only `CollectionModel`. I used the `ResultSetDataModel` class, but I do not understand which of the fields to put into the `<af:iterator>` value attribute.
Any comments would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through your ResultSet to create and populate any implementation of java.util.List. And once you have that List you have to create a getter for that List and then bind the value attribute of the `<af:iterator>` with the getter of the List.

```
class MyManagedBean {
  private List myData;
  public void initializeData(){
    ResultSet rs = getResultSetFromDB();
    while(rs.next()){
      myData = new ArrayList<>();
      myData.add(rs.getString("some_column"));
    }
  }

  public List getMyData(){
    return myData;
  }
}
```

and then in the JSP:

```
<af:iterator value="#{viewScope.myBean.myData}" var="data">
  <af:outputText value="#{data}" /> 
</af:iterator>
```

Comment: Thank you for that method. I was wondering if there was any way to avoid that extra iteration to convert from ResultSet to List? My query takes <1s to run, but the iteration takes ~3s to run, and I was hoping to eliminate it.

Comment: Try to use a ViewObject with the ViewObject containing the SQL query. And then try to create an iterator using the VO.